# Pass value from CodeBehind to Angularjs variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I would like to assign a value from codebehind to an angularjs variable. What is the best way to do this. (say I have a variable var UserInfo in app.js).

If the page is Default.aspx, I would do this in Default.aspx.cs for a JS variable.
**ASPX:**

```
<script>
    var idSeparator;
</script>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        AssignValueToJavascriptVariable();           
    }

  private void AssignValueToJavascriptVariable()
    {
   string idSeparator = string.Format("var idSeparator = '{0}';", Constants.ID_SEPARATOR);
   if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("IdSeparator"))
     {
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),   
       "IdSeparator", idSeparator, true);
        }     
    }
```

Comment: your angular code can access a global variable also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to use properties and from Default.aspx page call it e.g.

```
public string idSeparator {get { return "test"; }}
```

In aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var idSeparator = '<%=idSeparator %>';
 </script>
```

You can have your property to not be read-only and later on set the property value if you require that.

*Or alternatively you can use Asp.net hidden fields.*